# This item is temporarily unavailable please try again later

Tags: icloud, safari

I am trying to install an OS on my Mac computer, but keep getting the item is unavailable message after I enter my apple id and click install. So I was told I needed to go into safari and log into iCloud so that it would recognize my user ID on that computer. The problem I'm having now is when I go to iCloud all that loads is a blank page with iCloud in the top left corner.. Please help!!

Comment: What version of macOS and what *specific* Mac are you installing it on?

Comment: Welcome!  Your question lacks some important details like what version of macOS you’re trying to install, the model of your Mac and even the reason for the install?  Are you trying to fix a particular problem?

Comment: It's an IMac from early '09 that a friend gave me, when I first turned it on the disk utility popped up to install an OS. From the little bit of research I did it was telling me to download el Capitan and that's when I had all these issues.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos